# Trouble passing 2D array in C++ 8 Puzzle

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, sliding-tile-puzzle

For some reason I can't get the `distance` function to work. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

**Main Function:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

int distance(int**, int);

 int main()
 {
 int m;
 int goal [3][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,0}};
 const int N = 3;
 int intial[N][N];
 cout << "Enter in values: \n";
 for(int i=0; i<3; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++) //This loops on the columns
    {
        cin >> intial[i][j];  
    }
}


 cout << goal[0][0] << "\n" ;
 m = distance(intial,N);
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
 }
```

Manhattan Distance calculation!

```
int distance(int** array,int N)
 {

  int MSum = 0;
  for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){ //Transversing rows(i)
      for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) { //traversing colums (j)
        int value = array[x][y]; // sets int to the value of space on board
            if (value != 0) { // Don't compute MD for element 0
               int targetX = (value - 1) / N; // expected x-coordinate (row)
               int targetY = (value - 1) % N; // expected y-coordinate (col)
               int dx = x - targetX; // x-distance to expected coordinate
               int dy = y - targetY; // y-distance to expected coordinate
               MSum += abs(dx) +abs(dy);   
            }
        }

  }
  int m = MSum;
  return m;

 }
```

Comment: Can you success to compile it without any error? Can you figure out the source and target to calculate the [Manhattan Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)? Does the `int distance(int** array,int N)` want to calculate a sum of all distance?

Comment: The question is actually asking for passing 2D array in C/C++. Not the calculating manhattan distance. The syntax is wrong. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks basically correct as far as logic goes. The array you pass in should be compatible with the function declaration and implementation. Here is a sample declaration:

```
int distance(int array[3][3],int N);
```

Comment: Tried this but it gives me a error as follows:  [Linker error] undefined reference to `distance(int (*) [3], int)'

Comment: Did you try changing the function implementation as well?